# Programmatically flush JBoss 4.2.2 connection pool

Tags: jboss, jndi, connection-pooling

I'm running JBoss 4.2.2. I'm trying to determine the correct code to both:

1. Lookup the org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool
2. Perform a flush() operation on said pool.

I've found a couple other questions out there with no answers. I'm hoping this doesn't become yet another one of them.

The closest question I've found so far: https://community.jboss.org/message/637784

Answer (score 2):

Here's the basics using a quickie groovy example.
First, you want **jboss-4.2.2/client/jbossall-client.jar** in your classpath. 
Next, you need the JMX ObjectName of the data source. It may be helpful to find this in the JMX Console at **http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/** or however you have deployed. So the string value of the ObjectName is **the domain + ":" + the properties**.

For example:

[image]

The ObjectName is:  **jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=ManagedConnectionPool**.

Next, look up the RMIAdaptor in JNDI. This is the MBeanServer interfac that will allow you to invoke the **flush** operation on the target MBean. Then call the invocation. That's it.

```
import javax.management.*;
import javax.naming.*;

p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:1099");
ctx = new InitialContext(p);
rmiAdaptor = ctx.lookup("jmx/rmi/RMIAdaptor");
rmiAdaptor.invoke(new ObjectName("jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=ManagedConnectionPool"), "flush", [] as Object[], [] as String[]);
```

Make sense ?

**=====  Update =====**

If you are executing this from inside the JBoss JVM, you don't need the JNDI setup:

```
import javax.management.*;
import org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanServerLocator;

MBeanServer server = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
server.invoke(new ObjectName("jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=ManagedConnectionPool"), "flush", [] as Object[], [] as String[]);
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get to testing this as other priorities have popped up. It's in my queue though and I will be sure to circle back here when I've given it a try.